# How to correctly display multiply image in flexbox slider?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello i have flexbox slider, and 1 image fill all space like [this](https://pastenow.ru/57YIL) and wanna to know, how to place all different images here, they are have, but it display wrong, it must be like [this](https://pastenow.ru/57YIU)
how i think problem in `flex:1 0 100%;` but i don't know how to make this slider like [this](https://pastenow.ru/57YIU)

this code [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80Lha742/)

```js
(function() {
  var carousel, next, prev, seats;

  carousel = $('.carousel');

  seats = $('.carousel-seat');

  next = function(el) {
    if (el.next().length > 0) {
      return el.next();
    } else {
      return seats.first();
    }
  };

  prev = function(el) {
    if (el.prev().length > 0) {
      return el.prev();
    } else {
      return seats.last();
    }
  };

  $('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    var el, i, j, new_seat, ref;
    el = $('.is-ref').removeClass('is-ref');
    if ($(e.currentTarget).data('toggle') === 'next') {
      new_seat = next(el);
      carousel.removeClass('is-reversing');
    } else {
      new_seat = prev(el);
      carousel.addClass('is-reversing');
    }
    new_seat.addClass('is-ref').css('order', 1);
    for (i = j = 2, ref = seats.length; (2 <= ref ? j <= ref : j >= ref); i = 2 <= ref ? ++j : --j) {
      new_seat = next(new_seat).css('order', i);
    }
    carousel.removeClass('is-set');
    return setTimeout((function() {
      return carousel.addClass('is-set');
    }), 50);
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }


body{background-color:#383838;}

.container{
    width: 1170px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Museo Cyrl 900";
}



.w100{
 width: 100%
}

.wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
  padding-top:100px;
}

.carousel {
 display: flex;
 left: -100%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 transform: translateX(100%);
}


.carousel.is-set {
 transform: none;
 transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);

}

.carousel-seat {
 
 flex: 1 0 100%;
 order: 2;
}

.wrap ul li{
 width: 190px;
 height: 115px;
 
}
.sh_l{
 width: 100%
}

.carousel-seat.is-ref {
 order: 1;
}


.controls {
 padding: 2em;
 text-align: center;
}

.controls button {
 background: #fff;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 100%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.controls button:hover, .controls button:focus {
 background: #dd5a15;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--start of our partners-->
 <div class="our_partners">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="our_pr_title def_p w100">С кем мы работаем</div>
   <div class="slider_wrapper w100">
    <div class='wrap'>
     <ul class='carousel is-set'>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref'style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKD.png);">
      <a href="#" class="sh_l"></a></li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKQ.png);">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKD.png);">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKQ.png);">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKD.png);">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKD.png);">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKD.png);">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(https://i.paste.pics/57YKD.png);">
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='controls'>
     <button class='toggle'></button>
     <button class='toggle' data-toggle='next'></button>
    </div>

   </div>
   <!-- /.partner_slider -->
   <div class="bt_titlle def_p w100">С кем мы работаем</div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.our_partners -->
 </div>
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Hi! Please read [ask] and add the code here as a code sample, there is a tool for it in the editor. We need [mcve] to be able to help you.

Comment: @Esko i made it sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my advice for you, make it by yourself, main problem was, in `flex 1 0 100%;` i remove it, to parent add `display flex`; and also problem was, that image was incorret, image has no correct width and height, it means, that image is bouncing when click nav button, just try add image where width and height more that 300 px, and it will be okey.

to watch example better use this [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svw91r24/1/)

```js
(function() {
  var carousel, next, prev, seats;

  carousel = $('.carousel');

  seats = $('.carousel-seat');

  next = function(el) {
    if (el.next().length > 0) {
      return el.next();
    } else {
      return seats.first();
    }
  };

  prev = function(el) {
    if (el.prev().length > 0) {
      return el.prev();
    } else {
      return seats.last();
    }
  };

  $('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    var el, i, j, new_seat, ref;
    el = $('.is-ref').removeClass('is-ref');
    if ($(e.currentTarget).data('toggle') === 'next') {
      new_seat = next(el);
      carousel.removeClass('is-reversing');
    } else {
      new_seat = prev(el);
      carousel.addClass('is-reversing');
    }
    new_seat.addClass('is-ref').css('order', 1);
    for (i = j = 2, ref = seats.length; (2 <= ref ? j <= ref : j >= ref); i = 2 <= ref ? ++j : --j) {
      new_seat = next(new_seat).css('order', i);
    }
    carousel.removeClass('is-set');
    return setTimeout((function() {
      return carousel.addClass('is-set');
    }), 50);
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
body{background-color:#383838;}

.container{
    width: 1170px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Museo Cyrl 900";
}
.wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
}

.carousel {
 display:flex;
}

.carousel.is-set {
 transform: none;
 transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);

}

.carousel-seat {
 width: 200px;
 order: 2;
}

.wrap ul li{
 width: 185px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-right: 10px;

 
}
.sh_l{
 width: 100%
}

.carousel-seat.is-ref {
 order: 1;
}


.controls {
 padding: 2em;
 text-align: center;
}

.controls button {
 background: #fff;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 100%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.controls button:hover, .controls button:focus {
 background: #dd5a15;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--start of our partners-->
 <div class="our_partners">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="our_pr_title def_p w100">С кем мы работаем</div>
   <div class="slider_wrapper w100">
    <div class='wrap'>
     <ul class='carousel is-set'>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref'style="background: url(http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-8/Yellow-Forest-Background-Wallpaper-26004.png); background-size: cover;">
      <a href="#" class="sh_l"></a></li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-10/Magic-Forest-Tree-Wallpaper-28312.jpg); background-size: cover;">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-10/Tree-Roots-Magic-Forest-Wallpaper-28320.jpg); background-size: cover;">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-9/Forest-Lake-Desktop-Wallpaper-25667.jpg); background-size: cover;">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-10/Tree-Magic-Forest-Background-Wallpaper-28319.jpg); background-size: cover;">
      </li>
      <li class='carousel-seat is-ref' style="background: url(http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-10/Roots-Tree-Glare-Magic-Forest-Wallpaper-28315.jpg); background-size: cover;">
      </li>
      
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='controls'>
     <button class='toggle'></button>
     <button class='toggle' data-toggle='next'></button>
    </div>

   </div>
   <!-- /.partner_slider -->
   <div class="bt_titlle def_p w100">С кем мы работаем</div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.our_partners -->
 </div>
```